# Checking if Binary Search Tree is valid [HackerRank]

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to check if a BST is valid or not. Following is my code. Input from HackerRank **1 2 3 4 5 6 7**  My code is always returning **False** even when BST is valid.

```
/* Hidden stub code will pass a root argument to the function below. Complete the function to solve the challenge. Hint: you may want to write one or more helper functions.  

The Node class is defined as follows:
    class Node {
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
     }
*/
    boolean checkBST(Node root) {
        return isValidBSTHelper(root, root.data);

    }

    private boolean isValidBSTHelper(Node root, int limit) {

        if (root == null) return true;
        if (root.left != null) {
           if (root.left.data > root.data || root.left.data > limit) return false;
        }
        if (root.right != null) {
           if (root.right.data < root.data || root.right.data < limit) return false;
        }
        return (isValidBSTHelper(root.left, root.data) &&  isValidBSTHelper(root.right, root.data));
    }
```

Comment: What is the definition of the binary you are using? There are several types, if you are referring to a tree with the 2 nodes at max then it can be solved easily. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

Comment: You should provide a complete compilable code example. We cannot even tell if the values in your tree are really those from your picture. Your methods should be static. You should use a debugger to find the line that returns false. And you should use also an invalid tree (like replacing 19 with 51) to find bugs.

Comment: This is complete code. I am using HackerRank. Input is provided from HackerRank. I have also updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with 2nd if statement. Following solves the problem.

```
/* The Node class is defined as follows:

        class Node {
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;
         }
    */
        boolean checkBST(Node root) {
            return isValidBSTHelper(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        }

        private boolean isValidBSTHelper(Node root, int min, int max) {

            if (root == null) return true;
            if (root.data > max || root.data < min) return false;
            return (isValidBSTHelper(root.left, min, root.data) &&  isValidBSTHelper(root.right, root.data, max));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

HackerRank in **Is This a Binary Search Tree?**

Needs -> Check Condition as :

```
if (root.data >= max || root.data <= min) return false;
```

Comment: [The problem says](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/is-binary-search-tree/problem) "Constraints: 0 <= data <= 10^4" - why do you need to range check it at all?